# Waterfall Dialog keeps calling itself - how can I stop it?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

I am building a chatbot with bot framework composer and extend it with custom actions. These custom actions are mostly waterfall dialogs and until now they worked perfectly fine. Now I have the problem that one of these dialogs just won't end even if I call stepContext.EndDialogAsync() or stepContext.CancelAllDialogs(). Looking at the call stack and stepContext.Parent I am unable to figure out the problem. I even tried stepContext.Parent.EndDialogAsync() and still it jumps back to the first waterfall step. I want to jump back into the adaptive dialogue generated by the composer, so I can't use BeginDialogAsync().

Is there a way to literally "kill" the dialog? Or does anyone have an idea how to handle this issue? I can provide some code if neccessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you for your question. Is it possible if you could provide code snippet or repository to reproduce this issue?

Comment: More clarity is required for your question like code stack,etc

Comment: Thanks for your messages. Please check out this Dialog, it is the one I was talking about in my question: 
https://github.com/itsme-bigv/PassBot1/blob/unstoppableDialog/CreateModelDialog/Actions/BehaviorEditingComponent.cs
I believe the problem has its origin somewhere between the lines 167 and 200. 
I noticed, that the BotController gets invoked after the ConfirmPrompt in line 183 but does not really do anything.

Comment: Testing the bot; what is the flow to reproduce the issue? (how to get to that BehaviorEditingComponent in the Composer bot?)

Comment: @DanaV you can reproduce the flow the following way: 
1. start bot and connect to it with emulator
2. after greeting select "create new model from scratch" and give the model the name "test" (case sensitive; creates neccessary ressources for testing)
3. select "edit existing model"
4. select "edit subject behavior"
5. select "fullSub"
6. select random state 
7.  give state a random description
8. select yes, if asked to make it start state
9. select no, if asked whether you want to tell what the subject is doing next
--> dialog starts again with (5), although it should end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in the NextSteps composer dialog, set the 'Always prompt' to true:

[image]

this will enable stepContext.EndDialogAsync to work as expected from the last waterfall step.

```
return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ram, that works!! Happy new year

Comment: glad it worked  happy new year

Comment: This is what I am doing but I didn't realize that the Initial Dialog matters. I have to create a main dialog aside from the entry dialog and then it worked.